# How to convert strings to numbers in python while preserving fractional parts

Tags: python, floating-point

Here is example

```
In > int('1.5')
Out > 1
In > int('10.5')
Out > 10
```

But I want to keep values intact. How do you do it?

Comment: What do you mean by keeping the value intact? Keep them as floats?

Comment: 10.5 is not an integer. Integers are whole numbers with no fractional part. If you want to preserve a non-integer value, don't apply `int()` to it.

Comment: But, integers don't have a decimal point!

Comment: I think the asker thinks that using `int(my_float)` will truncate the passed float resulting in `my_float` being round. No, it won't be truncated.

Comment: An integer is a member of the set of [numbers without fractions](http://www.mathsisfun.com/whole-numbers.html)  When you convert to integer, by definition the fraction must be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers are only numbers that have no decimals.

```
-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,...,65535 etc...
```

Floating point numbers or Decimal numbers are allowed to represent fractions and more precise numbers

```
10.5, 4.9999999
```

If you want to take a string and get a numerical type for non-whole numbers, use [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)

```
float('10.5')
```

Here is a very simple elementary school explanation of [integers](http://www.mathsisfun.com/whole-numbers.html)

Here is the python documentation of [numerical types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = 10.5

foo2 = int(foo)

print foo, foo2

10.5, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer can one represent whole number.

If you have a known consistent number of digest after the the comma, I recommend multiplying the number by 10 to the power of X.

Or round the number to the nearest whole number